# Error in eval(substitute(expr), data, enclos = parent.frame()) : attempt to apply non-function

Tags: r

I am new to R and need some assistance. i want to solve a system of differential equations using Desolve. On running the code i am getting :  Error in eval(substitute(expr), data, enclos = parent.frame()) :
attempt to apply non-function
Called from: eval(substitute(expr), data, enclos = parent.frame()

'''
install.packages('deSolve')`
library(deSolve)

```
Tumor.model <- function(t, state, parameters) {

with(as.list(c(state, parameters)),{

# rate of change
dT0 <-(kappa*N)-(phi*T[0])*(1-(T[0]/Tmax))-((1-phi)*T[0])-(mu*Im*T[0])

dT1<- T[0]*(1-phi)-(Phi*T[1])*(1-(T[1]/Tmax))-
T[1](0)*exp((k/lam)*(1-exp(-lam*t )))-(mu*Im*T[2])

 dT2<- (phi*T[0])*(1-(T[0]/Tmax))+(Phi*T[1])*(1-(T[1]/Tmax))-
  T[2](0)*exp((k/lam)*(1-exp(-lam*t)))-(beta*T[2])*(1-(T[2]/Tmax))-
  (mu*Im*T[2])

 dT3<- (beta*T[2])*(1-(T[2]/Tmax))-T[3](0)*exp((k/omega)*(1-exp(-omega*t)))-
  (gamma*T[3])*(1-(T[3]/Tmax))-(mu*Im*T[3])

dT4<- (gamma*T[3])*(1-(T[3])/Tmax)-T[4](0)*exp((k/theta)*(1-exp(-theta*t)))-
  (alpha*T[4])*(1-(T[4]/Tmax))-(mu*Im*T[4])

dT5<- (alpha*T[4])*(1-(T[4]/Tmax))-T[5](0)*exp((k/psi)*(1-exp(-psi*t)))-
  (mu*Im*T[5])
  
dIm<-(eta*I[m])*(1-(I[m]/Imax))+(rho*T*I[m])/(epsilon+T)-(Xi*I[m])-
  (tau*T*I[m])
# return the rate of change
list(c(dT0, dT1, dT2, dT3, dT4, dT5, dIm))
})
# end with(as.list ...
}

parameters <- c(N=1.7*10^12,Tmax=1*10^9,Imax=800,T=1*10^6,phi = 0.0052,beta=0.003,
            gamma=0.045,alpha=0.055,Phi=0.0035,kappa=0.0025,k=0.500, 
            eta=0.0206,epsilon=1000,tau=1*10^-8,Xi=4.12*10^-2,lam=0.02,
            omega=0.02, theta=0.04,psi=0.04,mu = 1*10^-8, rho=0.835)
            
            
times <- seq(0, 100, by = 0.4)
state <- c(T0=20,T1=1,T2=1,T3=1,T4=1,T5=1,Im=5)

 out= ode(y=state,times=times,func=Tumor.model,parms=parameters)
'''
```

Comment: there are many capital T's in your code, which are `TRUE` values in R. `T[0] * 1` is `numeric(0)`, and is probably not what you want. I assume these `T[0]` are supposed to be T1, T2 T3 of your `state` variable?

Comment: T[0] i intend to refer to the initial value of a particular stage

Comment: And what does the singular T represent in `dIm` step of your `with`?  and the `(0)` in `T[5](0)` in `dT5`. These `T[5](0)` result in the error "attempt to apply non-function"

Comment: Thank you. T is representing average of the T values while T5(0) is representing the initial of T5